# Idiom or word for a very crowded place

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, russian

There is a popular idiom in Russian for describing a really crowded place: "(there's) no room for an apple to fall" ("яблоку негде упасть").

I struggle to think of anything similar in English, and the dictionaries I consulted were of no help, simply translating it as "crowded" or not even including it at all.

The context would be something and anything along the lines of

> The place was so crowded that [X].
>   The room was full to the extent that [Y].
>   The street/square was [Z].
>   At the top of the hat charts, there is [no room for an apple to fall].

Which is to say, I am not married to any sentence structure in particular — I'll gladly rewrite from scratch to use a vivid and idiomatic adjective or noun, word or phrase, metaphor or saying, rather than try and shoehorn it into a sentence it does not feel itself welcome in.

Comment: Out of interest, what is a *hat chart*?

Comment: @Tim: Something like [this](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network).

Comment: Interesting, in Dutch we have several expression like that, describing people being packed like sardines in a tin or herrings in a cask. Come to think of it, no English expression springs to mind :)

Comment: In Chinese, we also have colloquial expressions such as "packed like sardines" to describe a jam-packed subway train. I don't know if it was borrowed from English. Alternatively, we also say a place is so crowded that there is nowhere for a needle to be poked (inserted).

Comment: @inewbie the last one is interesting. English has sort of the exact opposite with "you could hear a pin drop" for a really quiet place. (Russian has "you could hear a needle fall"; I have to suppose they are somehow related, or are outright calques.)

Comment: Actually your phrase translates by Google translate as ["no room to swing a cat"](http://translate.google.com/#ru/en/%D1%8F%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C). But the words are literally "no room for an apple to fall" as you said.

Comment: @bobobobo: Google Translate is buggy as hell. It can't even translate such basic things as "Friday morning" from German. ([It translates it as "Thursday morning" instead](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SBZV6.png).) Consequently, I do not use Google Translate. Sorry.

Comment: Reminds me of the quote from Yogi Berra: "Nobody goes there anymore, it's too crowded."

Comment: In Spanish we say that the place was so crowded that you couldn´t fit a pin ("no cabía un alfiler") http://goo.gl/KavZzx

Comment: How about a zoo?

Comment: @RegDwigнt "So quiet you could hear a pin drop" allegedly comes from a style of auction in which a pin was stuck in the side of a lit candle and the last bid before the pin dropped was accepted. It's not impossible the Russian needle has the same history, but that's outside my ken…

Comment: Wall-to-wall people, analogous to wall-to-wall carpeting.

Answer (score 110):

If it is extremely crowded, you can say "packed like sardines in a can" or just "[packed like sardines](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/packed+like+sardines)" or "packed." This comes from the way sardines are tightly packed into cans when canned for eating:

[image: photo of sardines packed in a tin]

Strictly speaking, some people will object to this usage: both the place and the people in it can be said to be *packed*, but only the people can strictly be *packed like sardines* since the sardines are inside the can and the people are inside the crowded place. However, colloquially people will use the phrase in both senses. Also, most people just say *packed*:

> The subway wasn't working so the buses were all packed.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that expression being used in English :) Thank you :)

Comment: I believe this is the same derivation of **packed to the gills**?

Comment: Usage note: The room wouldn't be packed like sardines; the people or things in it would.

Comment: @cHao Technically, the people are packed into the room/bus/container. However, colloquially, people say "the bus was packed" or "the room was packed".

Comment: Yep.  The room can be packed, but it won't be "packed like sardines".  Perhaps it might be packed like *a can/tin of* sardines, but i don't know if i've ever heard that one either.

Comment: I don't know from which language this phrase originated but other languages have the equivalent phrase: Finnish `"kuin sardiinit purkissa"` and German `"wie die Ölsardinen"`/`"wie Sardinen in der Büchse"`. Interesting.

Comment: I think @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 is referring to a Singapore English idiom =)

Comment: This is actually a cliche, and should be avoided (because it is now mostly devoid of meaning).

Comment: @2er0, nope - I live in the U.S., and we say "the bus was packed" all the time. It's a very common phrase.

Comment: You'll say "the bus was packed", sure, but you won't say "the bus was packed like sardines". If you use the whole phrase (and not just the shortened _packed_), you should refer to people or items, not the container. If referring to the people in the bus, you would say "we were packed like sardines".

Comment: @terdon You can, idiomatically, modify the idiom by saying "*it's* packed like sardines" instead of "we're packed like sardines." The "it" does syntactically refer to the bus still, but the natural drift of language makes it sound correct to a native ear.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie huh, OK. Not this native's ear though. _It's packed_ sounds fine but not _it's packed like sardines_.

Comment: @terdon Good to know, since I haven't done any formal studies on its spread. ;) I suspect it's like swapping plural and singular nouns in some constructions: syntactically incorrect, acceptable in some (informal) contexts, but possibly not to all native ears.

Comment: I'm in PA, and *we were packed like sardines* is common enough that it wouldn't raise an eyebrow (or an *adipose eyelid*).

Comment: Мы обычно говорим, что едем в автобусе, как шпроты)

Comment: @oerkelens: it's used in French as well.

Comment: it is not directly related, but the same expression is used in French. `"Serré comme des sardines` is the French equivalent of `"packed like sardines"`.

Comment: An approximate expression is also used in Filipino, _parang sardinas_ ("like sardines").

Comment: @cHao I would say: "The room is packed like a **can** (or tin) of sardines"

Comment: @Cruncher: Yeah, i'd mentioned that one...but i don't remember ever hearing someone around here actually say it.  Does seem to be common enough on the web, though.

Comment: @cHao ah, I didn't see that comment. However I've never actually said "packed like sardines", I've always said "a can of sardines". I guess it's locale-dependant

Comment: I usually hear it in phrases like "**We** were packed like sardines".

Comment: @terdon, et al For clarity, the contents/passengers are packed like sardines. The container/bus is packed full/to the brim. Different expressions; different contractions; same apparent result… and outside the classroom, which listener might be confused?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin yes, of course. But, as you say, that's a different expression and not what we were discussing here almost 8 years ago. [The question was](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143782/idiom-or-word-for-a-very-crowded-place/143783?noredirect=1&__=1870471898#comment295511_143783whether) whether you could describe a bus, and not the people on it, as _packed like sardines_ and, apparently, some people do. Of course you can say the bus is _packed_, that was never contested.

Comment: @terdon Thanks and I'm sorry to come so late to the party… for whatever reason, this Question popped up on SE's announcements.

The reason I took the trouble to Post what I did was that the huge amount of effort above, in both Answers and Comments, left it clear that many contributors found the distinction hard to follow.

Whatever else, Tim Lymington seems to have nailed it…

Answer (score 52):

Packed to the gills

Packed to the rafters

Packed to the gunnels (from gunwales <- gun walls) (originally of a ship)

> A popular East Side bar, packed to the gunwales with arch young bankers and ersatz Now girls.

Pressed like olives/grapes

packed together tighter than two coats of paint

Bursting at the seams (the room was...)

As crowded as a beehive

> Big and poor and as crowded as a beehive.

And since we are photo-heavy...

[image: beehive]

"I would rather sit on a pumpkin and have it all to myself, than be crowded on a velvet cushion." - Henry David Thoreau

Comment: Living in Central U.S, I've personally heard "_Bursting at the seams_", though usually its when someone is telling a story and wants some extra flair to describe it. Not really a casual description if you're talking to one friend. The one I hear the most is probably "_(the place was) packed_" or "_it's packed in here_". I like this list the most myself, though the bee one reminds me of "_As busy as a bee_".

Comment: +1, nice ones. Never heard _pressed_ in that context before. I would have taken it to mean _under pressure_ or _forced_ or similar not packed. Do you mean _pressed together_?

Comment: @terdon - yes, pressed so hard together, it is as though we are olives being pressed for our oil. It can be used for more than one concert I've been to.

Comment: The wale in gunwale is not "wall." It is a band

Comment: Exactly, not a wall.

Answer (score 38):

*There was no room to swing a cat*? *We were pressed together like peas in a pod* (often used to indicate uniformity, but sometimes literal closeness)? *You couldn't fit a knife/cigarette paper between the [contestants]*?

Comment: "No room to swing a cat" generally refers to a small space, not necessarily a crowded one.

Comment: I actually like "no room to swing a cat" and think it would very much work. It's not hard to supply the information that the place was *not* small.

Comment: "Pressed together like peas in a pod" could be confused for "like two peas in a pod," which essentially means that two people mesh well together.

Comment: I've heard it expressed "no room to swing a [dead] cat without hitting X" to refer to a crowded space. When I've heard it used, it's always a dead cat -- perhaps that's just the macabre circles I run in, though.

Comment: @Charlie: I'm not sure that swinging a live cat would actually be an improvement.

Comment: @CharlieKilian I've heard that expression as well. "Can't swing a dead can't without hitting an [X]" Although, that's usually when you see an uncommonly large number of X, not necessarily crowded. If you walk down the street and see 10 firemen, you might say, "Can't swing a dead cat without hitting a fireman around here."

Comment: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10493/deleted-upvoted-and-popular-question-why#comment42723_10495 Not one reputable reference cited, not one link, but three answers packed in as many lines.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Thank you for spending so much of your time on ny answers: if you had looked at more you might have found that I have always believed that an idiom question needs no citations, indeed that copy-pasting dictionaries makes for a bad answer.

Comment: No, don't flatter yourself. I was looking for SWRs that generated over 25 answers, and I found one here.

Comment: And in my language, there`s a related idiom - no room for a mouse to swing its tail.

Comment: @KatieKilian et al Where does swing a "dead" cat come from, d'you know? Many people seem to think the original "swing a cat" literally refers to a feline, which might make swinging a "dead cat" humorous, however pointless it was.

"Officially" though, the "cat" to be swung is the "cat o' nine tails", ie the nasty whip traditionally used on ships for flogging miscreant sailors, which would make that "dead cat" not only pointless, but meaningless…

Answer (score 35):

In British slang, we often describe a place as "[rammed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ram?q=rammed#ram__12)", when full:

> **(be rammed)** *British informal* (of a place) be very crowded:
>       *the club is rammed to the rafters every week*

[image]

Comment: Smells like [*crammed*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Middle-earth_food_and_drink#Cram) to me.

Comment: Perhaps it originally *was* crammed, but I would always say rammed now.

Comment: Agree with "crammed" rather than "rammed". Rhyming with these is "jammed" leading to "jam packed". To me "rammed" suggests pushing as in "the shot was rammed into the musket".

Comment: In British English it's definitely *rammed [full]*, not *crammed [full]*. The metaphor here is [ramming a cannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramming) with shot before firing.

Comment: I hear the word *rammed* used by my Southern friends and not by any Northerners, is it a London thing?

Comment: Well I'm as Northern as they come and I say rammed a lot.

Comment: In Cardiff (Wales) we use rammed, and I often hear people use the word "rammout" which I believe is a contraction of rammed out (though I've no clue why.) Heaving and packed are also common.

Comment: I first saw "rammed" instead of "crammed" in the old British music papers, a couple of decades ago. Still sounds slightly odd to me. I'm Scottish, and I suspect it is (or was) a London thing.

Comment: *Rammed* is a great piece of UK slang (possibly localised to London or Southern England? That's where I am myself so I'm not sure). It doesn't just mean "full of people", it means "full of people in a good way - full because it's popular, exciting because it's full". I think the Chinese *rènao* is similar: "[busy places with many people having a good time and lots of chat and laughter.   Restaurants with rènao – hustle and bustle, hot and noisy with an edge of excitement.](https://herschelian.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/hustle-and-bustle-its-hot-and-noisy/)"

Comment: @Ste, et al Could you drop the "often", please? 'We often describe a place as "rammed" when full' is pushing it, and a lot. I never heard that use of "rammed" until the 2016 Corbyn train fiasco, and not more than three times since.

Answer (score 28):

Adding to the nice suggestions so far, I've found one dictionary that offered ["**there is hardly breathing space**"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/breathing+space).

> sufficient space in which to move, work, etc.: *The train was so crowded that there was hardly breathing space.*

Comment: +1 I've also heard this phrased as "there's no room to breathe".

Comment: also, when somebody gets hurt and people crowd around, _"Give him some air"_ or _"give him some room to breathe"_ is often said to get people to make some room for the hurt person.

Comment: Yes but while "Give him some air/room to breathe" is almost always figurative, isn't "there's hardly breathing space" literal… people are too often crushed to death in crowds, although thankfully that's rare here in England.

Answer (score 23):

How about ***"[chock-full](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chock-full?q=chock%20full)"***?

> *adjective*
>   [*predic*.] *informal*
>       filled to overflowing:
>           *my case is chock-full of notes*

And the British term ***"[chock-a-block](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chock-a-block)"***.

> *adjective*
>   [*predic*.] *informal*, chiefly *British*
>       crammed full of people or things:

Comment: I've never heard this used to describe a crowded place.

Comment: No?  I have heard it a fair few times and [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=chock+full+of+people&oq=chock+full+of+people&aqs=chrome..69i57.3542j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=%22chock+full+of+people%22) has a number of hits.

Comment: Same here, _chock full of people_ is the phrase that comes to mind.

Comment: Or just "chockers".

Comment: I've heard my parents use it, can't recall anyone my age doing so.

Answer (score 19):

More modern formulations for a crowded place include the idiom that a place is ***teeming with people***. The OED says that *teeming* as an adjective means

> Abounding; swarming; crowded.

Another word you might be looking for is the noun ***throng***.  The OED includes these two relevant senses for it:

> **2**. Pressing or crowding of people; an act of thronging or crowding; crowded condition.
>
> **3**. *concr.* A crowded mass of persons actually (or in idea) assembled together; a crowd.

There is also a verb *throng* to accompany the noun, whence derives the adjective ***thronging*** meaning pretty much the same thing as *teeming*. Per the OED:

> The action of the verb *throng*; pressing; crowding.

Comment: Much like `throng`, consider `mob` (n.) and `mobbed` (v.t.) ("The mall was mobbed on Black Friday"). See: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mobbed

Comment: One thing these have that most of the other entries lack is the implication of motion.  A place that's packed to the gills or crowded like sardines implies everyone is so crowded there's no room to move.  But a throng or a place teeming or swarming with people implies they're busily moving around despite being crowded together.

Answer (score 16):

One venerable — nay, agèd — word for overcrowded is ***opplete***, which is both an adjective and a verb.

Quoth the OED regarding the adjective:

> **oˈpplete****,** *ppl. a.* *Med.* *Obs.* Also **6** **opplet**.
>
> **Etymology:** ad. L. *opplēt-us*, pa.
>    pple. of *opplēre*: see next.
>
> Filled up, crowded.
>
> - **1545** **Raynold** *Byrth Mankynde* P j, - The coti
>     lidons be opplete, stopped, & stuffed with yll humours.
>
>   **1578** **Banister** *Hist. Man* **i.** 34 - The posteriour part [of the leg] is opplet, and filled with much store of flesh.
>
>   **1646** **J. Hall** *Horæ Vac.* 134 - How should they not be 
>     opplete with grosse humours?

Quoth the OED regarding the verb:

> **oˈpplete****,** *v.* *Med.* *Obs.* *rare*.
>
> **Etymology:** f. ppl. stem of L. *opplēre* to fill up, f. 
>   *ob-* (**ob-** <sup>*(def#1)*</sup> <sup>*(def#d)*</sup>) + *plēre* to f
>   ill.
>
> *trans.*  To fill up, fill to repletion.
>
> - **1620** **Venner** *Via Recta* ii. 41 - They..opplete the
>     ir bodies with waterish, crude, and windy humors.
>
>   **1620** **Venner** *Via Recta* iv. 71 - That it be not..oppleted with much 
>     fat.

Comment: Same etymological origin as "replete". I like it.

Answer (score 15):

The place was so crowded that you couldn't [swing a cat](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/not_enough_room_to_swing_a_cat). 
The room was full to the extent that [there is no elbow room](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/elbow+room).
The street/square was [packed to the rafters](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/packed_to_the_rafters).
A crowded event might be described as [standing-room only](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing-room_only).

Comment: I don’t understand why people pick on cats so mercilessly.

Comment: @tchrist A man who carries a cat by the tail learns something he can learn in no other way. - Mark Twain

Comment: I've heard "to swing a cat" refers to the old practice of beating rugs with cat-o-nine tails, not the actual animal.

Comment: The phrase "standing room only" is commonly used for audiences, but would be understood if applied to rooms as well.

Comment: This is suspected to be a folk etymology. There is evidence that the phrase "enough room to swing a cat" was already in common use by 1665, however although the cat-o-nine-tails was certainly being used by then, there's no evidence that it was then *called* a cat-o-nine-tails.

Comment: @RichardWyatt You wouldn't beat a rug with a [cat-o-nine tails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_o%27_nine_tails); and I'm not certain that the cat is alive in the idiom.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Indeed, the phrase is often in the form "swing a dead cat", which makes it unambiguous.  (Also rules out a cat-o-nine tails since you wouldn't need to specify that it's dead as it was never alive.)

Comment: However, "That's let the cat out of the bag" comes from the cat-o-nine tails.

Comment: @MartinMcCallion No. No it doesn't. Care to buy a [pig in a poke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_in_a_poke)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch How interesting. _Blue Peter_ lied to me all those years ago. I think it was _Blue Peter_, anyway. Some programme like that.

Comment: @MartinMcCallion Peter Purves (or the other presenter) was just misguided.

Answer (score 14):

["Like Picadilly Circus"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piccadilly_Circus#In_popular_culture) is commonly used in en-GB.

[image]

For a more international audience, I'd go with "packed like sardines".

Comment: I think that "like Piccadilly Circus" also has connotations of being extremely busy and lively, and not simply being full of people. A funeral could be *packed*, but it wouldn't be *like Piccadilly Circus*.

Comment: Relatively speaking, it's practically *deserted* in your particular picture. [Here's an](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2010/09/10/article-1311002-008C3F9B00000258-23_470x339_popup.jpg) (admittedly, *older*) one with rather more people!

Comment: Not my picture. My answer was edited.

Comment: *"packed like sardines"* was actually the first thing came up to my mind.

Comment: In Brisbane we might say something along the lines of "it's like Queen St Mall in here!" (Queen St being a busy pedestrian shopping street in the Brisbane CBD). I'd imagine there are a lot of regional variations on this theme.

Comment: Oh yeah, this picture is so much better, @Matt.

Answer (score 10):

- 'A sea of people.'
- 'A writhing sea of humanity.'

Comment: 'a sea of people' reminds me a [Chinglish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinglish): People Mountain People Sea 人山人海, idiomatically "huge crowds of people".

Comment: Not to be confused with a Mexican wave.

Answer (score 9):

"It's like the Black Hole of Calcutta in here." This refers to the tiny dungeon in which British prisoners of war were held in June 1756 after the fall of Fort William, Calcutta, where (allegedly) the vast majority perished from suffocation or heat exhaustion because so many people were crammed into such a small space.

For a one word equivalent of "crowded": crammed, rammed, heaving, packed.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. +1 for the excellent simile.

Answer (score 8):

A local, possibly New England, expression is "stuffed tighter than a turkey" (or other colorful variation).

Also, [as this Houston Chronicle article demonstrates](http://www.chron.com/life/rodeo/article/Club-packed-tighter-than-a-pair-of-Wranglers-2105555.php), *packed tighter than a pair of Wranglers* (or designer jeans) is a relatively common expression.

Answer (score 7):

This might work ... how about 'jam-packed' ?

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jam-packed

Answer (score 6):

***The place was so crowded you had to go outside to change your mind.***

This quip is [often used](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22outside%20to%20change%20your%20mind%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) when talking about the size of a cramped room or house, as one writer mentioned in an [article](http://www.bankrate.com/finance/real-estate/lying-listings-fool-more-homebuyers-1.aspx) about language sometimes used by real estate agents:

> For example, he cites the commonly used term "cozy" and says the connotation to savvy Realtors is that there isn't much space in the house.
>
> “It triggers the Henny Youngman in us: ‘This house is so small that you have to go outside to change your mind,’” Boyd says.

Comment: Sounds worthy of Groucho (surreal pun on not enough room to change your tie, say).

Answer (score 5):

Let's not forget the conventional and all-purpose *full house*.

> ### full house
>
> *noun*
>
> an audience, or a group of people attending a meeting, that fills the venue for the event to capacity.

Comment: Where are those citations from? Please tell us the name of where you got those from, and if applicable, also a link. If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 5):

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com):

> ## [brimming](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/brim)
>
> adjective
>
> - fill or be full to the point of overflowing.
>     "a brimming cup"

and

> ## [overflowing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/overflow?q=overflowing)
>
> adjective
>
> - (esp. of a liquid) flow over the brim of a receptacle.

and

> ## [overcrowded](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/overcrowd?q=overcrowded)
>
> adjective
>
> - filled (accommodations or a space) beyond what is usual or comfortable.

Comment: Where are those citations from? Please tell us the name of where you got those from, and if applicable, also a link. If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Comment: @tchrist to accuse the user of plagiarism (see your meta [post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4973/what-to-do-about-missing-source-attributions/4981#4981)) is very objectionable when clearly the citations are **linked** definitions taken from a dictionary and placed in blockquotes. I think you are overstating your case. Would leaving the answer simply at "brimming" "overflowing" and "overcrowded" have been preferable for ELU?

Comment: @Mari-LouA The answer on the meta post clearly states that the source must be explicitly named in plain text. This has not been done.

Comment: @tchrist nowhere do I see or could possibly interpret the user as appropriating the written material as his own. Via meta: *posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own*. There are three separate links directing the reader to the source, i.e. Oxford Dictionaries. The "answer" is not an example of plagiarism as you stated in your meta post [*The Ugly: examples of completely unattributed copying (plagiarism):*](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4973/what-to-do-about-missing-source-attributions)

Answer (score 5):

Irish has the expression *dubh le daoine*, and a literal translation of that — “black with people” — is used in Irish English to describe a crowded space. According to a post on [boards.ie](http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=2056665409), this can sometimes be abbreviated to “it’s black in here” to describe a crowded space.

(Interestingly, I learn also from boards.ie of an equivalent expression in French: *être noir de monde*.)

Answer (score 4):

[Packed](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20packed) is the easiest word that comes to mind.

> ## packed
>
> *noun*
>
> - cram a large number of things into (a container or space).
>
>   - "it was a large room, packed with beds jammed side by side"
> - (of a large number of people) crowd into and fill (a room, building, or place).
>
>   - "the waiting room was packed"

Comment: Where are those citations from? Please tell us the name of where you got those from, and if applicable, also a link. If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 4):

**"It's like Grand Central Station ..."**

Referring to the hustle and bustle of the very famous and busy [railroad terminal in New York City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Station).

Comment: Ever since seeing "Last Train Home", sometimes when I'm in a crowded place, I will say "It's like a train station on Chinese New Year's".

Comment: This is a good comparison but isn't really an idiom. You could also say "like the Japanese subway" or any other well-known crowded place.

Comment: Or Like Times Square on New Year's Eve : http://ww1.hdnux.com/photos/17/10/76/3968900/3/628x471.jpg and http://media.salon.com/2012/12/new-years-eve-security.jpeg4-1280x960.jpg

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I disagree... I think it's clearly an idiom, and I've heard it used as such (specifically to mean crowded with people) all my life.

Answer (score 3):

"Assholes and elbows"

In a crowded place (such as a bar or night club), it's often hard to maneuver for all the assholes and elbows filling up the place.

Answer (score 2):

Irish slang - possibly moribund by now: "jammers" as in - the bar was "jammers"

Answer (score 2):

The place was **chocker**.

This basically means the place is full, and is presumably an abbreviation of chock-a-block.

You could also say the place was **heaving**.

Comment: In Australia, I believe the place would be *chockers*. I've never heard or seen either form used in North America, however.

Comment: ...And depending upon how far into the middle of Australia you get "chockas". The vernaculars into which this spelling variant is included are niche to say the least.

Comment: This is the abbreviated form of [Ste's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/143798/23292)

Comment: Not really, as though chocker is an abbreviated form of chock-a-block, it is a different word, and somebody who would say chocker wouldn't necessarily say chock-a-block.

Answer (score 2):

How about, "It was *a mob scene*."

Or perhaps "*an ugly mob scene*," if it was anything like our local shopping malls this past holiday season...

Comment: Mob scene denotes not only crowdedness, but also rowdiness.

Comment: On the other hand, it is the winter bash hat race, so rowdiness may apply.

Answer (score 2):

Infestation.  There's no reason to elevate one species above others.

Comment: Maybe there isn't. But there's no real reason to **lower** any species either, which is what *infest* does.

Comment: Lowering can only take place if you've already elevated from equality.

Answer (score 1):

Depressingly, the sole local discotheque was [packed like the hold of a slave ship](http://amhistory.si.edu/onthewater/exhibition/1_4.html). People were crammed in there [like the black hole of Calcutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Hole_of_Calcutta).

Comment: Sorry, Philanthropistrog. I missed your prev Calcutta ref.

Answer (score -2):

*Bazaar*
It is urdu for market . It is suitable as asian markets are usually crowded and noisy.

Answer (score -3):

"That was a *clusterfuck*."

The first thing to come to my mind when I read the question.

E.g. [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cluster%20Fuck&defid=6590079)

A corpus search [(Google for clusterfuck and crowded)](https://www.google.com/#q=clusterfuck+crowded) yields 1.2 million results.

Comment: along these lines there is the military slang *charlie foxtrot*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help].

Comment: In particular, my understanding of that word is that it's a cock-up (or, more likely, a succession of them), which doesn't necessarily involve many people.