# In AE, is "tin" used instead of "can" to designate an eco friendly BPA free can of sardines?

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage

I've always thought that "can" was the typical term to refer to a can of sardines (or the like) in AE, and "tin" the BE equivalent, until I recently stumbled across "tin" used instead of "can" on a US website to designate a can of smoked trout.

And so, I was wondering whether "tin" could have migrated across the Atlantic from the UK to the US, and gained ground into regional or mainstream AE to designate -- along with "can" -- a small airtight flat container adapted for storing a pack of processed fish. Or, does "tin" have a specific meaning to it in AE?

I thought it might designate a can made of special metallic alloy suitable for food products, and also good for the environment.

> Consider the Web page in question: [source](http://www.colestrout.com/search.aspx?find=Tin)

Comment: Of course a UK 'tin', containing anything from soup to rice pudding, is not made of tin. It would be prohibitively expensive if it were. But at one time these cans were electro-plated with tin for preservation purposes. I don't know if they still are, or indeed what they are made of - steel?, aluminium?

Comment: Look up the history of tin cans, BTW.  It's interesting.  You will see that at one time, tin cans were kept behind the counter of a grocery or general store due to their significant cost.  They were hand soldered, and painstakingly canned.  Mechanization and canning improvements made them the ubiquitous cheap things we know today.

Comment: Nourished Gourmet, there isn't a strict rule about using the word *tin*, in the UK. It is common but, the word *can*, is also used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For what it's worth, it may be a regional thing, but in Monterey, California, we had a very big sardine industry not long ago. Sardines were produced in the **canneries** on a street called **Cannery Row**. This was made famous in 1945 in the John Steinbeck novel by the same name: **Cannery Row**, and later in 1982 in the movie by the same name.

Sardines are canned in canneries using a process called canning, and you generally won't find the word tin mentioned anywhere. ([source: The little fish that we **can**: California’s sardine industry, now and then](http://www.ethicurean.com/2009/12/09/sardines/))

Online stores in Monterey call the containers **cans**, as this picture shows (although the single cans seem to be unavailable, they can be bought in a twelve pack).

[image: sardine sold in cans]

The American company Walmart describes their sardine products as being sold in a can:

[image: pull top sardine can]

If I look on Amazon.com, the suppliers describe their products both ways, with can being preferred only slightly, if it's mentioned at all. This surprises me, because I can't recall ever having heard anyone refer to a *sardine tin* in the United States (except maybe my wife's grandmother, but she was from Bermuda).

### Update

Since the Ngram Viewer is popular here, I've run one on AE usage, and then BE usage. There is definitely a preference inversion in the corresponding literature. But this distinction is stronger in AE, going for *can*, not *tin*:

American English
[image: ngram American English]

British English
[image: ngram British English]

### Update 2

One more thing I forgot to address is your question about BPA-free containers. I think you will still find them called cans, as in [this article](http://www.treehugger.com/green-food/7-companies-you-can-trust-to-use-bpa-free-cans.html), *7 Companies You Can Trust to Use BPA-Free Cans*, which never mentions *tin* as what the BPA-free containers use, nor do they call the containers *tins*. Yet they still achieve BPA-free results for their products.

Answer (score 10):

Originally, all cans were 'tin can' because cans were lined with tin.  The Brits took **tin**, we took **can** for the short name.

The flat rectangular shaped can, however, is a **tin** even in the US, and always has been.

Comment: +1 Even though many cans and many tins are no longer loned with tin.

Comment: @Oldcat Ok. Then, would you mind and explain this to me, Oldcat http://www.whfoods.com/genpage.php?tname=foodspice&dbid=147

Comment: It appears to be a web page on sardines. You will have to be more specific on what the issue is.

Comment: @bib - These days I doubt any can is lined with tin, or has any tin content.

Comment: You don't hear _tin_ used that way in the US any more. _Can of sardines_ is the idiom. _Tin of sardines_ sounds vaguely UK.

Comment: Metal containers of that shape, rectangular with rounded sides, even containing games and candy are still called tins.

Comment: @NourishedGourmet - In American English, **canning** is the process of hot-packing foods into rigid airtight containers, no matter what those containers are made of or what shape they are.  (The flat, rectangular package is still called a "tin" in AE, even though the sardines inside are "canned".) **Tinning**, on the other hand, has nothing to do with food in AE; the most common meaning is "applying solder to the ends of wires".  The link you provided is from an American company; a British site  might have said "tinned sardines" instead.

Comment: *Can* of sardines, not *tin* - at least not in my lifetime.  Where do you AmE speakers still hear "tin"?  (I'm US Midwest)

Comment: Sardines are not that popular any more, but you'll find an endless number of articles on how to reuse an *Altoids tin*, whether ["manly"](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2011/01/30/22-manly-ways-to-reuse-an-altoids-tin/) or ["girly"](http://www.pinterest.com/tammya9555/amazing-altoid-tin-uses/). Granted, Altoids are marketed as a British import, even though they are owned by Virginia-based Mars, sold by Chicago-based Wrigley, and manufactured in Chattanooga, Tennessee.

Comment: I say "can of sardines/anchovies" even though I know that they are in what I would correctly identify as a *tin*, a flat, rectangular, round-edged can. Someone else does, [too](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143782/idiom-or-word-for-a-very-crowded-place/143790#143790).

Comment: @JohnLawler While nowhere near as common as *can*, tin is still heard in AE. Google *tin of sardines* to see some examples.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say all flat metallic containers of this type are exclusively tins.  It is perfectly acceptable to say *sardine can* when you're talking about a tight space!  It is also perfectly acceptable to call all flat oblong cans tins, though.

Comment: @KristinaLopez It is used.  Not nearly as commonly, but it does seem to apply more to a flat oblong can, than a round cylinder.

Comment: @bib Tin foil, too.  Tin is waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay too expensive compared to aluminum and stainless steel.

Comment: Not my day...it *is* an Altoids "tin", not a "can". Yikes.  I'm giving up! lol!

Comment: @bib:  I said it's not heard that way, and that's what I meant. Google does not record events of language; it records **writing**. Phrases that are written are not phrases that are **heard**. Writing is not language.

Comment: I don't agree entirely, but even so the original question is if **tin** is a **new** term with an exciting new meaning, not if **can** is more popular now. Of course, he may edit the question to say something else any minute.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't disagree that Google does not record spoken language (unless it links you to a recording with audio). It was offered as an indirect indication of what *I* still hear, albeit not so frequently. And I am not sure that written language is not language. While it is meta at best, it is a form of communication for many things that are never spoken out loud. Are those written passages not in a *language*?