# Catchphrase or word for overcrowded

Tags: synonyms, catch-phrases

I am trying to think of catchwords or phrases related to a place being too busy. Something catchy.

Examples I've found on the internet:
packed, crammed, jammed, packed-like-sardines, choc-full, etc..

Thanks and hope this question is suitable for this board

Comment: Have you looked anywhere to see what options you can find?

Comment: Here's a few I though of: jam-packed, elbow-to-elbow, standing room only, packed like sardines … But I see this has been discussed before: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143782/idiom-or-word-for-a-very-crowded-place

Comment: Board? What is this the 90's?  We're a gosh darn site.  And a fairly **popular** one at that.

Comment: @Armen Safieh-Garabedian An example of how you want to use that phrase might help...

Comment: [Nobody goes there anymore. It's too crowded.](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/y/yogiberra100418.html)

Answer (score 2):

*Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary*, third edition (2008) has this entry for "to the gills":

> **to the gills** INFORMAL used in expressions to mean completely full: *By the time the fourth course was served, I was stuffed to the gills*. • *The restaurant was packed to the gills*.

Another vivid phrase is "as close [or *tight*] as white on rice," as in this excerpt from John Wideman, *Hurry Home* (1970):

> So there was the mag[istrate] soft talking and trying to move down the street with all them [people] crowded round him. **Close as white on rice**. He was like a stick being carried away by the gutter or a leaf in the wind.

Answer (score 1):

Along the same lines as your examples, you could use the adjective from the past participle of 'throng', 'thronged':

> **throng** *v.intr.*
>   To gather, press, or move in a throng.

And likewise the adjective from the past participle of 'swarm', 'swarmed':

> **swarm** *v.intr.*
>   To be overrun; teem.

(Both definitions from [*The Free Dictionary*](http://thefreedictionary.com/).)

For a variety of possibilities (take your pack), [*WordHippo*](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/crowded.html) is a good resource:

- congested
- jam-packed
- cramped
- huddled
- loaded
- populous
- crushed
- massed
- mobbed
- overflowing
- stuffed
- chock-full
- dense
- elbow-to-elbow
- filled to the rafters
- fit to bust
- mob scene
- sardined
- wall-to-wall

Answer (score 0):

***It's a zoo***

From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/it-s-a-zoo)

> Also, what a zoo. This is a place or situation of confusion and/or
>   disorder.

The OP said "overcrowded" or "too busy".  A place that is overcrowded is either already a place of confusion and/or disorder, or is on the verge of becoming so.

Example:  "This restaurant is a zoo!  Let's go somewhere less crowded."

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia:
[**cluster fuck**](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_United_States_Marine_Corps_acronyms_and_expressions&redirect=no#C) (also Clusterfuck, Charlie-Foxtrot) -"Chaotic and messy situation from multiple mistakes or problems happening in rapid succession." I generally use this term to describe overly packed areas.

> "Let's not go to Starbucks now, it's probably a cluster fuck."

It's also used in gaming circles:

> "Someone throw a nade, there's a cluster fuck of demon spawn."

If you are looking for something without any profane expletives, [**goat rope, goat rodeo and goat screw**](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_United_States_Marine_Corps_acronyms_and_expressions&redirect=no#G) also have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

**teeming**    [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/teeming)

v. teemed, teem·ing

> abounding in people, fish, insects, et;  dense or bustling

Answer (score 0):

I thought [asses to elbows](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Asses%20to%20elbows) was a pretty silly expression until I saw my baby's ultrasound.  A womb is truly asses to elbows.