# Idiom for 'lots of people'?

Tags: expressions

I think there was an idiom to describe 'lots of people', and the expression was related to truck... like tons of truck? or loaded by truck? I can't remember what it was. Does anybody know? If there is no such thing, is there any idiom to describe lots of people that will make a long line or that will fill all the big trucks?

Comment: related: [Idiom or word for a very crowded place](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143782/idiom-or-word-for-a-very-crowded-place)

Comment: other idioms are useful ... without involving trucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably thinking of the word **[truckload](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/truckload)**:

> 3 : a large amount - *truckloads of money*

<sup>merriam-webster.com</sup>

It's used in far more situations than to describe people, but "a truckload of people" is an acceptable usage.

Comment: boatload may work too

Comment: @lbf - Not when the OP wants a word relating to "truck"...

Comment: 'Truckloads' doesn't work if you're restricted to the M-W definition. *_A large amount of people._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - What's wrong with "a large amount of people". Sure, it's not idiomatic, but I don't see any grammatical problems.